# Live site menu links pointing to staging site pages

Tags: menus, staging

We have recently published our staging website. However, the header menu links on the new live website are still pointing to pages in the staging site.

How do I make links in the header menu on the staging site 'relative', so that when the staging site goes live, the menu links point to corresponding pages in the live website, rather than the staging website? What is the best practice to set up a menu or individual links in the menu in a staging site to avoid having this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked for any 'custom' links in your menu items (on the Appearance, Menu page)? There shouldn't be any - all links should go to a 'page'.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access WP CLI, you can use [the `search-replace` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) to search the database for the old URL and replace with the new URL.